# Rails + Amazon RDS : latency issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, caching, amazon-rds

I have an app whose database is being migrated to amazon RDS.

I experienced a significant drop of performance, due to the latency of the queries between RDS and our server (like 30s of loading time only because of the queries). There is no explicit caching, and the requests could be optimized a bit more, but this is still more than 10x slower than with a local database.

I this kind of performance drop expected? If yes, is there a way to use a cloud database with similar performances as a local one?

Comment: RDS is really best suited to stuff running on AWS. Remote use of RDS is going to put you at the mercy of the intervening connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been some reported issues with poor performance of RDS by people. Although amazon as far as I've seen hasn't acknowledged these issues.

RDS (which is just a custom version of mysql) uses the ESB for the storage backend, and as I'm sure you are well aware of the failure they just had with that service.

I've read a lot of companies just running their own mysql DBs in EC2 instances becuase it's showns to have more reliable performance.